# MYSQL select with relation into itself and order

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
id | parent | question
---------------------------------
1  | 0      | Question 1
2  | 0      | Question 2
3  | 2      | SubQuestion 2
4  | 0      | Question 3
5  | 2      | SubQuestion 2
```

How can I select column question so that it'll order into such:

```
Question 1
Question 2
 Subquestion 2
 Subquestion 2
Question 3
```

Is there a way at all?

Comment: See JOIN. That's it.

Comment: review [Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) here

Comment: I'm kinda lost because there's only one table here involved ... the page shows more than 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Order by case when parent = 0 then id else parent end, id
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/275d0/1)